# Enabling responsive GUI while processing

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a lengthily processing in my winform when I click a button; namely, i'm loading lots of files and processing them. For the duration of the processing, my GUI is frozen and unresponsive which is a problem since the processing can take an upward of 10 minutes. Is there a way of putting the code in some sort of bubble or something so I can use the GUI while processing the files? Maybe even add the "Cancel" button.

**EDIT**: René's solution works, also here's `progressbar` control I also wanted:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {  
       progressBar1.Maximum = ValueWithTOtalNumberOfIterations.Length;
       IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(value => { progressBar1.Value = value;});

       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           var tempCount = 0;

       //long processing here
       //after each iteration:

           if (progress != null)
           {
               progress.Report((tempCount));
           }
           tempCount++;        
        }            
   }
```

Comment: Look at async / await https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: You can use BackgroundWorker. Refer this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx For cancel button operation use CancelAsync method.

Comment: Yes there are different ways to achieve this. You should probably search for async-await (if you are using net fw 4.5 or higher) as you already tagged this correctly and then come up with your try ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply make your button's click handler `async` and start a `Task` for your long running operation:

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false; // disable button to not get called twice

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // process your files
    }

    button1.Enabled = true; // re-enable button
}
```

The compiler turns this into a state machine. The control flow is returned to the caller (the UI) at the `await` keyword. And execution of this method is resumed when your `Task` has completed.

---

To use a "Cancel"-Button you can use a [`TaskCancellationSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or simply define a flag that you check while you're processing your files, and return if the flag is set (by the click handler of your "Cancel" button):

```
private bool _stop = false;

private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stop = true;
}
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false; // disable button to not get called twice

    _stop = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // process your files
        foreach(var file in files)
        { 
            if (_stop) return;
            // process file
        }
    }

    button1.Enabled = true; // re-enable button
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! But I'm getting an error now within my processing code, like ThreadStateException on my `DialogResult result = folder.ShowDialog();`. Says that current thread must be set to STA mode before OLE calls can be made. I know I shouldn't be asking this here, but can do you know how to fix it?

Comment: oh you should not open another dialog inside the task, because it's executed on a different thread than ui.

Comment: Ah I see. The button that starts the processing first opens folderBrowserDialog to select the files. Should I then position the Task.Run thing below that?

Comment: Yes, putting the `Task.Run` below all GUI related operations did the trick. However new error also pops up for the similar reasons because I have a `textbox` below the button that displays a confirmation message after each individual file has been processed. Should I just not use any GUI related operations during `Task.Run` or is there a way to still use textbox` in this case?

Comment: You can use `BeginInvoke()` or use an `IProgress<string>` to report progress back to the ui thread. There is a lot on SO on how to update winforms ui from a different thread.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If it's not too big of an ask, could you also add `IProgress<>` example on how to send progress to `progressbar1` that is on UI thread? I've been busting my head around this problem for the past 12 hours..

Comment: @Romy I think it's enough to post the [first](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) [two](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) google results for "IProgress<T> example" :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114191/discussion-between-romy-and-rene-vogt).